# Having eclipse CDT automatically detect g++ version in PATH

Tags: eclipse

I have some C++ projects that I build on both g++ 4.2.4 and 4.4.3.  I want eclipse to inspect the g++ version and construct the `/usr/include/c++/${g++-VERSION}` directory in the Paths and Symbols configuration of my CDT project.  Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out in the Project Settings:

C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> Enable "Automate discovery of paths and symbols"